# Issue related landscape view in ios 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my application support landscape orientation it working well in iOS 6. But in iOS 7 my device is change but   `self.view` is not supported landscape orientation   why ?? anybody have faced same issue as mine ? then please help me at on.

my code of orientation is,

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Interface Orientation Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Where i was wrong ??

Comment: return yes for shouldAutorotate

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but sorry Not helpful for me :(

Comment: you are try to force to landscape or try portrait to landscape. which is one you are trying

Answer (score 0):

If you want the application to support both change the method

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

to

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    DebugLog(@"");

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but sorry Not helpful for me :(

Comment: do you want to support then just landscape orientation? or both landscape and portrait?

Comment: My device is properly change as landscape orientation but self.view is not  changing ??

Comment: can you provide more code or screenshots? It is difficult to understand the problem...

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
    return YES;
}

 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;

}

 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but sorry Not helpful for me :(

Answer (score 0):

could you try this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have this in your custom UIViewController? Try with only this method.